# Laravel echoing object property after checking for Existence

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel there is a shortcut method for checking and printing variable if it exists:

> {{ $name or 'Default' }}

Is there any similar syntax for object properties? Because that kind of syntax will throw an error in case I'll try to check an object property for existence:

> {{ $object->property or 'Default' }}

I know I can solve that with plain PHP like that:

> {{ isset($object->property) ? $object->property: 'Default' }}

But isn't that odd? Object properties are longer than variables and they also have to use longer syntax?

Comment: Actually the `or` syntax should work. It compiles to `isset`

Comment: That is  what I thought - but it throws an error :(

Comment: What does the compiled view look like? (One of the files in `storage/views`)

Comment: @lukasgeiter I'll post it once I get home. I am at work now and the project is on my PC at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use.

```
{{ @$object->property ?: 'Default'}}
```

The "@" is a [Error Control Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

I haven't seen a Laravel specific method.

Comment: Thats' what I wanted :D