# Custom shortcode parser

Tags: php, laravel, shortcode

I am trying to create a custom parser for shortcodes in PHP, but I need directions on which php function (or maybe even php library) to use. Note that I am using Laravel 5, so packages are welcome too.

For example, I have a string in this format:

```
Hello {{user.first_name}}, your ID is {{user.id}}
```

I have a `$user` object containing these parameters. I'd like to check if all shortcode parameters within the string exist in the object, if not, I'd like to return an error, and if yes, I'd like to return the parsed string which would equal to:

```
Hello John, your ID is 123.
```

## UPDATE

Please note that I'm building a REST API and this would be used in an automated email system. I need the result in a string within the controller so I can use it in my mailing function before the json response is returned.

Comment: May be this could be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554946/laravel-echoing-object-property-after-checking-for-existence

Comment: Have you considered using [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), might be a bit of overkill if you're just using it for variables.

Comment: @Alok, as I see this is for blade... I need this string parsed within a Model/Controller, not in a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your template style [Mustache.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) is the right library to achieve your goal.

Use Composer. Add `mustache/mustache` to your project's composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "mustache/mustache": "~2.5"
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if(isset($user->first_name) && isset($user->id)) {
    $m = new Mustache_Engine;
    return $m->render("Hello {{first_name}}, your ID is {{id}}", $user);
    //will return: Hello John, your ID is 123.
}else {
    //trigger error
}
```

**Update 1:**

If your data object is an `Eloquent` instance, you can use the following class to automatically throw errors in case of missing variables:

```
class MustacheData {

  private $model;

  public function __construct($model) {
    $this->model = $model;
  }

  public function __isset($name) {
    if (!isset($this->model->{$name})) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("Missing $name");
    }

    return true;
  }

  public function __get($name) {
    return $this->model->{$name};
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
try {
    $m = new Mustache_Engine;
    return $m->render("Hello {{first_name}}, your ID is {{id}}", new MustacheData($user));
}catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    //Handle the error
}
```

Comment: This is cool, now I need to find a way to make the parameter validation dynamic, I want to be able to use all parameters available from multiple objects without making the conditions static, but check if the parameters exist according to the input string. Is this somethig Mustache can do? Anyway, this solves my problem too, I'll accept it if no other option is provided.

Comment: What's the type of your object `$user` ?

Comment: All of the objects used would be single row Eloquent results (`$user = User::find($id)`). I feel like I need to clarify my previous comment, it's not very clear. I want to get all shortcode uses within the string, check if those variables are available in the objects provided, and then parse or return an error. Actually I need an array with all shortcode occurrences within the string so I can do the check before rendering.

Comment: Please check **Update 1** !